# Exporting .tif from referenced mosaic dataset does not use functions in raster dataset

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1, export, mosaic

Very frustrating little issue in ArcGIS 10.1 -- I have a referenced mosaic dataset of terrain data that has a series of functions inserted (slope and several iterations of a statistics function to simplify and smooth the resulting mosaic).  When I export the project to a .ai file (OR even the data as a .tif), the resulting .ai or .tif file produces my slope image WITHOUT the functions (i.e. unsmoothed).

Anybody think of anything i might not have tried to make it work?  Why would it display the mosaic with the functions running on the screen, but not the graphics without it?

Comment: Are you applying these functions on the raster layer?

Comment: Aaron, I inserted the functions to the mosaic dataset (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Editing_function_chains_in_a_mosaic_dataset/009t00000045000000/).  So yes, they are applied on the rendered raster I see on my screen, but the exported images are produced without running these functions, i.e. original unsmoothed data.

Comment: What functions are you using?  You can often use other methods such as running a 3x3 mean moving window over the image to achieve a smoothing effect.

Comment: Sara, did you ever find a solution? I am having the same problem. I don't understand why I cannot save the rasters with the functions applied. I have tried every which way, and can only export the rasters one at a time via the Image Analysis workflow. I have hundreds of images and really want to find a way to export the functions using geoprocessing tools in model builder.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend one of two approaches using ArcGIS.

1. A 3x3 low pass smoothing filter using [Filter (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000qq000000)
2. A moving window approach using a mean or median statistic in a 3x3 neighborhood [Focal Statistics (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000qs000000)

Comment: Thanks Aaron! -- I just prefer the mosaic functions because my mosaic covers much of the Andes, so it's great to run the focal stats function on the fly rather than on a giant Andean-scale raster mosaic.   Alas... I'll clip out little bits and run the focal stats on those.  Still can't figure out why it wouldn't work though; I did the same thing last month and it worked just fine!